# yfinance doesn't give latest data

Tags: python, yfinance

It is 13:15pm in London and the stockmarket has been operational for a good while - no problems there. So why does the 4 line Python script below give me data only upto Fri last week May 20th?

```
import yfinance as yf

isin = "AAL.L"
df = yf.download(tickers=isin, period="7d", interval="1m", auto_adjust=False, prepost=False)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
                                 Open        High  ...   Adj Close   Volume
Datetime                                           ...                     
2022-05-16 09:30:00-04:00  145.550003  145.800003  ...  145.350006  2608713
2022-05-16 09:31:00-04:00  145.354507  145.830002  ...  145.399994   496718
2022-05-16 09:32:00-04:00  145.360001  145.889999  ...  145.419998   383700
2022-05-16 09:33:00-04:00  145.460007  145.460007  ...  144.880005   592115
2022-05-16 09:34:00-04:00  145.149994  145.149994  ...  145.059998   358300
...                               ...         ...  ...         ...      ...
2022-05-20 15:55:00-04:00  137.320007  137.485001  ...  137.475006   629720
2022-05-20 15:56:00-04:00  137.470001  137.589996  ...  137.470001   708316
2022-05-20 15:57:00-04:00  137.470001  137.600006  ...  137.589996   641932
2022-05-20 15:58:00-04:00  137.589996  137.779999  ...  137.761597   778017
2022-05-20 15:59:00-04:00  137.764999  137.889999  ...  137.550003  1496703

[1949 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: It's working alright in google colab

Comment: Weird. The last 2.5 days data (Monday, Tuesday and this morning) is missing for me. What can I do? This has always worked fine...??

Comment: where are running your code?

Comment: perhaps library setup/version or internet network issue? this is weird.

Comment: From pycharm (the IDE I use for Python development...)

Comment: I updated yFinance (using pip) but the problem persists. It is weird, and a big issue for me.

Comment: just ran on my pycharm, working ok, change your virtual env and run again

Comment: Did that (thanks for the tip), but alas the problem remains. Sometimes when I switch my computer off and on it works for a while (not always though!) but then after a while the problem recurs and from then on *all* shares I try give data only up to Fri last week. I'm tearing my hair out!

Comment: This is an interesting issue, if the problem persists, then I suggest (if possible for your case) run the scraper on the cloud (colab, check naas package, github action, vps) Also create a github issue as well.